# Tools for compare data before writing into db

Tags: database, web-scraping, amazon-dynamodb, compare, comparison

I am writing a project which needs to scrape data from a website, I am using pyspider, and it runs automatically every 24 hours(scraping the data every 24hours). Problem is , before writing the new data entry into the dB, I want to compare the new data with the existing data in the dB.

1. Is there a tool/lib I can use?
2. I am running my project on aws, what’s the best tool I can use to work with aws?
3. My idea is to set up some rule for the data to update/insert into the dB, but when the new data is somehow conflict with rule then I will be able to view the data/scrape log（where the tool will label it as pending）and waiting for admin to do further operation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[List of data compare, synchronization and migration tools.]https://dbmstools.com/categories/data-compare-tools

visit there. it might be helpful